# How to find the match by reading lines and add the value in to separate variables if multiple matches found.= using Python

Tags: python

```
>(0, 'fc1/36 is down (Link failure or not-connected) ')
>(1, ' Port description is Test_A ')
>.(2, ' 0 frames input,0 bytes ')
>(3, ' 0 discards,0 errors ')
>(4, ' 0 invalid CRC/FCS,0 unknown class ')
>(5, ' 0 too long,0 too short ')
>(6, ' 2483450 frames output,99338000 bytes ')
>(7, ' 0 discards,0 errors ')
>(8, ' 10426519 input OLS,0  LRR,0 NOS,842364 loop inits ')
>(9, ' 1087644 output OLS,0 LRR, 9882699 NOS, 1087505 loop inits ')
>(10, ' Last clearing of "show interface" counters: 2w 3d ')
```

I am trying to find a match for "discards," and want to capture it in variables. In this scenario, I get two matches "0 discards,0 errors" in line 3 and 7. How can I capture the first match in a seperate variable named  "input_discards" and the second match in a variable named "output_discards"?

I am using line.find("discards,") > 0: and getting the following output

(3, ' 0 discards,0 errors ')
(7, ' 0 discards,0 errors ')

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, especially [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  Stack Overflow is not a coding service.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to get the desired output based on your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yourreturn = (3, ' 0 discards,0 errors ') (7, ' 0 discards,0 errors ')
input_discards = yourreturn[0]
output_discards = yourreturn[1]
```

This saves the whole first tuple to the input_discards and the second one to the output_discards variable. If you want to save only a part of the returned tuples, and for example ignore the line number, you could do:

```
input_discards = yourreturn[0][1]
```